# What are the exact languages supported by the WPF in-built spell checking?

Tags: .net, wpf, spell-checking

I understand only 4 languages are supported within WPF in-built spelling, English, German, French and Spanish are available.  But is only en-US supported, how about en-GB?

Documentation on this topic in MSDN docs. seems sparse at best.  Where can I locate exact details on the languages supported?

The reason I ask this is that I would like to add settings within my WPF app where you can select the language for the spell check or have an option for disabling the in-built feature.  Within these options I would like to list the exact languages that are supported, whether it is en-US or en-GB etc.

Comment: I've found the spell check feature in WPF to be a bit flaky to be honest.  We've had problems whereby you can type a word spelled correctly (words that are the same in GB and US English) yet they are highlighted as incorrect, yet the next time you type the same word it will not be flagged as an error.  Also, sometimes you can paste incorrectly spelled words into the TextBox and they are not highlighted, even though the text could be complete nonsense.

I know that doesn't answer your original question, just thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that.  Hopefully it will improve in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only English, French, German and Spanish for now. You need to install the latter three with the [.Net Language pack](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23067). You can also add some limited custom jargon to those languages (see [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2009/10/02/custom-dictionaries.aspx)), but there is no way to add an entire dictionary.