# WPF spell check specific language

Tags: wpf, spell-checking

We are developing an application that needs a spell checker in multilanguage beginning. For cases in English, French, Spanish and German applying the `RichTextBox` works perfect language with xml property: `lang = ...` But when we apply the concealer with the Catalan language, this does not work. We tried putting the property xml: `lang = "ca"` which is code that recommends `rfc 3066`. I understand that .net should take the words of the languages I mentioned before somewhere to check whether it is correctly written. Are any language pack for Catalan must be installed? Are not .net support for this language?

Comment: Please see my [response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37753666/492471) to another similar question.

Answer (score 1):

> In .NET Framework 4, WPF provides dictionaries for English, French, German, and Spanish.

This is from the MSDN on Spellcheck : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

It also suggests how you can add custom dictionaries with lexicon files, which should help you implement what ever languages you need.